# storing foreign key, not from the form POST method, but by form data I already have

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am storing 'payment' model instance via form POST method but I have the data of the foreign key field already, because I am coming from a page which list the objects of 'student' model. I am storing the field of foreign key by input type="hidden" html element.

but when I submit, it shows error

```
> Cannot assign "u'1'": "payment.student" must be a "student" instance.
> Request Method:   POST
> Django Version:   1.5.2
> Exception Type:   ValueError
> Exception Value:  
> Cannot assign "u'1'": "payment.student" must be a "student" instance.
> Exception Location:   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-> > > > >packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __set__, line 405
>Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
>Python Version:    2.7.3
```

This is my model:

```
class payment(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey('student',db_column='student')
    dateTime = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    amountDue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

I added later added `db_column='student'` but it might not have really taken effect in mysql database.

Comment: You'll need to show the view code where you handle the form.

Comment: Also show the template where you have the hidden field.

Comment: No need to say "I am a noob" - we were all new at one point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to assign `int` for `payment.student`.
Assign `student` instance.

```
payment.student = student.get(pk=1) # Desired value `1` for foreign key assumed
```

Moreover you should follow coding style rules (read about `PEP8`):

- class names started with capital letters
- field names not started with capital letters
- variables and fields don't use camel case - class names do

Your code will work without this rules but as Python Developers we have some standards for readable code.

And in Django you don't have to define primary key field - it's created automatically and accessible with `instance.pk`.
And I'm not sure if you really want your foreign key to point to `student` column of `student` table.
And you can just import `student` model if it's defined in other module.

So with these corrections your class definition should be like:

```
from other_app.models import Student

class Payment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    date_time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount_due = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Now any Payment instance has implicit field `pk` which stands for primary key.
And finnaly a line in your view with styling corrections:

```
payment.student = Student.get(pk=1) # Desired value `1` for foreign key assumed
# payment is instance so all lowercase here
# Student on the right side is a class so started with capital
```

Comment: in that case it says: Cannot assign "u'student object'": "payment.student" must be a "student" instance. also I post data like <input type="hidden" name="student" value="{{student}}"> or value={{student.Id}}

Comment: Normally, if you have the integer for the PK of the related model you want to assign to a FK field, it's better to do so using the auto-created `_id` field rather than unnecessarily spend the overhead to look up or create an instance.  But the model definition here has `db_column` defined.  I suspect the OP may be having problems based on having that `db_column` setting match the field name.

Comment: That's another problem @XavitojCheema, you have put {{ student }} in your template, so student instance is converted to unicode and this is rendered into HTML. Use {{ student.pk }} in your template.